# closing a jquery-ui dialog one at a time

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, dialog

I'm having an issue with multiple jQuery UI dialogs. What I want is that I can have multiple dialogs, and a click on a button with the class ".close-modal" will only close the dialog in which that button was located. Now, first for a little background: I have a simple function in the "main" parent of the site, which will open a modal dialog by clicking on a link with the class ".modal";

**In the parent**

```
function modal( href, title ) {
    var $dialog = $('<div></div>');
    $dialog.html('<iframe class="modal" name="' + title + '" style="border: 0px;" src="' + href + '" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>');
    $dialog.dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        height: 650,
        width: 950,
        title: title
    });


    $dialog.dialog( 'open' );

    $(document).bind( 'close-dialog', function( ) {
        $dialog.dialog( 'close' );
    });
}

$('a.modal').click( function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault( );
    modal( $(this).attr( 'href' ), $(this).attr( 'title' ) );
}
```

This code works the way I want it to. To open a dialog from a dialog, I call the parent window's modal function with the correct parameters, so that multiple dialogs can be displayed within the parent:

**In the dialog**

```
( function( $ ) {
    $(document).ready( function( ) {
        $('a.modal').click( function( event ) {
            event.preventDefault( );
            parent.modal( $(this).attr( 'href' ), $(this).attr( 'title' ) );
        }

        /** Trigger the close-dialog event on the parent to close the current dialog. */
        $('.close-dialog').click( function( ) {
            parent.jQuery( parent.document ).trigger( 'close-dialog' );
        });
    });
})( jQuery );
```

So, in essence; I've defined an event on the parent window ("close-dialog"), which can be called by the code within the iframe which will call $dialog.dialog( 'close' ); This works brilliantly; I can create multiple dialogs, even from within dialogs, but the issue is that once I click a `button.close-dialog`, it closes *all* of my dialogs.

Is there any way to determine from which dialog the event was called? Or bind the event to the current dialog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use jquery modal's buttons option.

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $( ".myModals" ).dialog({
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            Close: function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

This should do it for all your modals in one go, and the buttons it creates only apply to themselves. Hope that helps!

Comment: It sort of does help, but not fully. I have buttons in the modal windows, which should close it, but they didn't. I've redesigned the application to use only one modal window instead, which seems to work. I'll accept your answer though, as it's the only one :)